# Likelihood ratio normal distribution?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, normal-distribution

Could someone help me fill in the steps to show that
$$
\exp \left\{\frac{1}{2 \sigma^{2}} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_{i}-\mu_{1}\right)^{2}-\left(x_{i}-\mu_{0}\right)^{2}\right\} = \exp \left\{\frac{n\left(\mu_{0}-\mu_{1}\right)}{\sigma^{2}}\left(\bar{x}-\frac{\mu_{0}+\mu_{1}}{2}\right)\right\}
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding the sum at the exponent you get

$$\frac{\Sigma_i\left[x_i^2+\mu_1^2-2\mu_1x_i-x_i^2-\mu_0^2+2\mu_0x_i  \right]}{2\sigma^2}=\frac{n(\mu_1^2-\mu_0^2)-2n(\mu_1-\mu_0)\overline{x}}{2\sigma^2}=$$

$$=\frac{n(\mu_1-\mu_0)}{\sigma^2}\left[\frac{\mu_1+\mu_0}{2}-\overline{x}  \right]$$

....to get exactly your result multiply both factors by $(-1)$